# ReferenceOne with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, symfony

I've got a problem with Symfony2.0 BETA3 and MongoDB. I want create a Document, where a Field References to another Class, this might look like this:

```
namespace test\TestBundle\Document;
use test\TestBundle\Document\Location;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;

/**
* @ODM\Document(collection="locationcache", repositoryClass="test\TestBundle\Document\LocationCacheRepository")
*/
class LocationCache
{
    // many more fields...

    /**
     * @var Location
     * @ODM\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="test\TestBundle\Document\Location")
     */
    protected $location;

     /**
         * @param Location
     */
    public function setLocation(Location $location)
    {
        $this->location = $location;
    }

    /**
     * @return Location
     */
    public function getLocation()
    {
        return $this->location;
    }
}
```

But if I want to find a location by $id like this

```
class LocationCacheRepository extends DocumentRepository
{
    public function findByLocationID(MongoId $locationID)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder()
            ->field('location.$id')->equals($locationID)
            ->sort('year', 'asc')
            ->sort('month', 'asc')
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute();
    }
}
```

I will get this error

```
 No mapping found for field 'location' in class 'test\TestBundle\Document\LocationCache'.
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a Document

```
Array
(
    [_id] => 4dd637e706936bbcc0ac012d
    [days] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [money] => 9
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [money] => 21
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [money] => 38
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [money] => 6
                )

            [18] => Array
                (
                    [money] => 6
                )

            [19] => Array
                (
                    [money] => 3
                )

            [31] => Array
                (
                    [money] => 11
                )

        )

    [location] => Array
        (
            [$ref] => location
            [$id] => 4dd554c91c911a6606000000
            [$db] => test
        )

    [money] => 94
    [month] => 1
    [year] => 2011
)
```

I don't know what's the problem with the class. Could please someone help?

Thanks in advance!

- Monty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want search on any location field you need to use 'embedOne' instead of 'referenceOne'. 
ReferenceOne not copy location fields into parent document, it just data like this (i don't remember exactly):

```
{
 refId: '1',
 refColl: 'locations',
 refDb: 'location_database'
}
```

But in general if you need query only by location id you just need take a look how location reference looks like in mongodb using mongoshell or some other tool.

So you query will be like this:

```
   ->field('location.$refId')->equals($locationID)
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your answer, I've added a document, and it looks like, I should realy use $id, not $refId.

Comment: Same issue with embedOne or referenceOne, can't find mapping for location.

Comment: @Monty i guess you need regenerate hydrators an proxies an put in under application cache -> http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/mongodb_odm/1.0/en/reference/console-commands.html

Comment: Won't symfony generate these, if I delete /app/cache/*? I used app/console doctrine:mongodb:generate:proxies
and app/console doctrine:mongodb:generate:hydrators and results in Fatal error: Class 'LocationCacheRepository' not found in .../vendor/doctrine-mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/DocumentManager.php on line 474

Comment: (generation completed successfully) looks like, something is really wrong with my class...

Comment: Have you placed hydrators and proxies to the cache folder?

Comment: they will automaticly placed to cache folder: Hydrator classes generated to ".../app/cache/dev/doctrine/odm/mongodb/Hydrators" and Proxy classes generated to ".../app/cache/dev/doctrine/odm/mongodb/Proxies"

Comment: It works now with current commit of symfony and doctrinmongodb. Thank you very much :D!